# Как использовать componentdidmout в модальном окне правильно?

Tags: reactjs

При вызове модалки на странице

```
{showVacationRequestModal ?
    <ModalVacationsRequestDetails
        open={showVacationRequestModal}
        onClose={this.hideVacationRequestModal}
        title={selectedVacationRequest.topic}
        selectedVacationRequest={selectedVacationRequest}
        width="md"/> : null}
```

Вызывается его `componentdidmount` и делает запросы которые хотелось бы делать только при вызове модалки!

Как правильно это сделать? делать запросы в `redux` и передавать `props` или же есть другой метод?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть замечательная библиотека [redux-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-modal)

Именно с помощью этой библиотеке можно делать запросы в `componentDidMount()` и именно при вызове модального окна, а когда будете закрывать модальное окно будет срабатывать `componentWillUnmount()`

Comment: Я нашел ответ через afterOpen в компоненте react-modal